# Youtube data api asks for consent while accesstype is set to offline

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, google-api-php-client

I have implemented the Google Youtube data api in a website, to let users see videos of certain channels. I have read the documentation from Google on how to use it, and used the offline accesstype since it lets the API autorize itself, refreshing the access token after it expires.

The API is working, but i still get prompt for autorization after 1 hour (default time for expiration of access token), while having the code that refresh the access token automatically.

I didnt provide all the code im using, only the code that handles the API setup and expiration of tokens, since the other code works fine.

Any help to what im doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated.

**Updated**

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile($config);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly');
$client->setAccessType('offline');

if(file_exits($aToken){
$accessToken = file_get_contents($aToken);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  if($client->getRefreshToken()){
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken());
    file_put_contents($aToken, $client->getAccessToken());
  } else {
      authorize();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying your refresh token but not actually using it to fetch a new access token.

```
$client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
$client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken());
```

My sample [Oauth2Authentication.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/YouTube%20Data%20API/v3/Oauth2Authentication.php)

Comment: Thanks, i also didnt have any refresh token because i didnt set the approvalprompt parameter to "force". So that and the fetch method solved the problem. Interesting that there is no mention about the fetch method in the docs for the youtube data api, only place i could find it was in the people api.

Comment: Google documentation isnt the same for all apis some are better documented then others.  Drive is good for php so is google analytics my project has them generated for all the apis.   Remember to accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Accepted and upvoted your answer now. Yeah, ill that code sample looked good so ill probaly use it in the future for Google apis.